# Get JSON Result from popup window. Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've got a pop-up window that calls a RESTful backend to do Oauth authentication, but when the result is returned, it displays the JSON in the popup window rather than closing the popup window and storing the JSON in a model. How do I fix this?

```
this.socialLogin = function(provider) {
  var url = urlBase + '/' + provider,
      width = 1000,
      height = 650,
      top = (window.outerHeight - height) / 2,
      left = (window.outerWidth - width) / 2,
      socialPopup = null;

  $window.open(url, 'Social Login', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',scrollbars=0,top=' + top + ',left=' + left);
};
```

Comment: Why do you need the extra window in the first place? If it's on your domain you could use postMessage API to pass data back to main window

Comment: When I try that, nothing happens at all.

Comment: $window.postMessage('Message', url);

The issue is that the backend is redirecting to the Social login page from Twitter or Facebook

Comment: Did you check the backend implentation of the oauth in your server. I did this type of thing before with jawbone. What it does is, usually it asks for a callback url once oauth succeeds. Now the url it is calling on success must be returning a script telling it to close the window. This is how it was implemented in our case. You might give it a try.

Comment: It's a rest api, so all it returns is json. The bcallback goes into passport, and it returns json of the user data. The window never closes, rather it just shows the raw json.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  Running into the same problem.

Comment: The issue is probably on the back-end side then. It looks like it's returning JSON data instead of HTML. Do you make any HTTP request with $http in Angular? That should be the only use case where JSON would be returned from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation described is likely not the best way to solve your problem in Angular. I am assuming that this is written inside of a controller. If so, making a call to a backend service is best done with the `$http` service. To do so,

controller.js

```
angular.module('example')
  .controller(['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) {

  $scope.socialLogin = function(urlEnd) {
    $http.get(urlBase + '/' + urlEnd) // Should probably be posting here...
      .then(function(res) { // Your JSON response here
        $scope.doSomethingWithTheResponse(res.data);
      }, function(err) { // Handle your error
        $window.alert("We got us an error!\n" + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    }
  }])
```